# Unpleasant comment after downvoting an answer

Tags: discussion, down-votes, etiquette, comment-flags

I asked a question on Stack Overflow. Someone provided just a link that was supposed to contain the answer, with no accompanying description or assistance of any kind.

The link didn't answer my question at all, so I down-voted the answer and I got an unpleasant comment back from this guy asking if he should commit suicide because the down-vote 'affected' him too much.

I didn't get any other answer and I want to start a bounty but I prefer to close this question because of his comment and to start a new one.

Is there a way to ask for removal of comments like that? Or should I just close the question?

Comment: I suppose this is the question you're talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964755/hgroup-how-can-i-change-order-of-elements

Comment: you are correct. this is the question, i thought it may be not nice to post it here.

Comment: On meta, it's always better to post links when talking about a specific question/answer.

Comment: thank you. i'll know that for next time. i donno how i missed the flag icon :) now the comment is gone! so thanks a lot for everything! :)

Comment: Whoops, his answer is now a comment.  Damn.

Answer (score 16):

You can flag it as offensive if you want.

Alternatively, just ignore it. It's just a really dumb comment.

A general word of advice though: While it's perfectly within your right to downvote answers to your own questions, I would be very careful with it - after all, the answerer donated some time to help you. A downvote from the OP themselves is often perceived as rude.

I would downvote only egregiously lazy, wrong, or outright malicious answers to my own questions. In all other cases, I would add a comment saying that the answer doesn't help me, and leave the  downvoting to the community.

Comment: I disagree, downvotes are what downvotes are. It doesn't matter who does it, if the answer is not helpful he can (and should) downvote it. I think it's even more important for the OP to rate all answers (-1;0;+1)

Comment: @Juan fair enough, but one should be really sure it's not their fault then. If I'm not 100% sure whether my question was clear enough in the first place, I would be *very* careful when downvoting an answer that doesn't help me. (Not saying there's anything wrong with @ufk's question - talking in a general way here)

Comment: Well, I agree with that, but you were making a point for the general case. Of course you could be careful if you think your question was not clear. In my case, I don't downvote unless they are wrong, and I do it consistently in my questions as in other's.

Comment: If an answer is unhelpful or incorrect the OP should downvote, nothing rude about it. Ultimately it is the OP who knows what will or won't be helpful (granted you can express this through "accepting" an answer).

Answer (score 8):

Click the little flag icon (beneath the up arrow) to the left of the comment, and select the appropriate option in the dialog box. Also, if you can link us to that question here, we can help get rid of it faster.